# Display serializer field as 'named' field instead of a primary key field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a Django REST framework API and are running into some issues with using the Serializers. I'll try to isolate the problem a little.  Basically there are the `Room` and a `Location` models.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='room')
    ...
class Location(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

and the corresponding serializers,

```
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = serializers.RelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ('uuid', 'location')
class LocationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('uuid', 'name')
```

I've explored the many ways to change the display of `uuid` to the location name including the use of `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` and also using the above `serializers.RelatedField()`, and they do work.  As a reference, see the JSON output below.

```
{
    "uuid": "491ab09d-qqqq-wwww-eeee-5801dbac0fef",
    "location": "Kota Kinabalu", 
    "created": "2014-09-03T07:52:45.399Z", 
    "modified": "2014-09-03T07:52:45.530Z"
}
```

However, I am not able to do a model.save() on Room since Django or rather the database (postgresql in my case) complains that the location_id is empty.  I think its due to the fact that when I send a POST request to the API endpoint /api/rooms/ the location_id is left blank when I modify my RoomSerializer.

If one uses a default ModelViewSet, you would see that the Location field is missing from the default form.

How do I use serializers properly such that I could display the name of the location ("Kota Kinabalu" instead of a uuid string like 6e6acbbb-xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-1cf1a5bac22c) and I am still able to accept a correct POST request?

Answer (score 3):

(I'm moving `quik_silv` comment into an answer)

You should use the SlugRelatedField provided by DRF: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield

In this case all you have to do is add a field like: `location = serializers.SlugRela‌​tedField(slug_field='‌​name', read_only=True)`. Note the use of the parameter `read_only`, which should fix the problem in creating model instances.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using customized UUID related field. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/openbudgets/openbudgets/blob/develop/openbudgets/commons/serializers.py).

Comment: Your suggestion could probably have fixed my issue.  However, it did lead me to realise that the solution was in the documentations all along. I ultimately used `location = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name')`

Answer (score 0):

I know it had been a long time and you might have already got the solution. But I am posting here the solution how I implemented this. After reading a bit of docs, I came across a method named `to_representation()`. I used this method to convert the data which is being returned in form of primary key to any other form. You can refer about this method in the docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields).